# What's the difference between a milestone and an accomplishment?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

While adding an entry to my [SO Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/3357935), I came across a required field asking whether my entry was a project, milestone, or accomplishment.

[image: A type of project, milestone, or accomplishment...]

**I'm a bit confused about the difference between milestone, and accomplishment.**

For instance, let's say I wanted to add [Eagle Scout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Scout_%28Boy_Scouts_of_America%29) to my developer story. Would that be categorized as a milestone or an achievement?

To make things more confusing, the "Category" section only appears when adding a Milestone to my Developer Story. Wouldn't that mean I'm adding a milestone? Or does that make an accomplishment a type of milestone?

Comment: This sort of question is predicated on the assumption that the questionnaire etc is itself using language correctly. Perhaps they see milestones as major accomplishments. The question then arises: 'What is _major_?'

Comment: Even though dictionaries are often not great tools to use when trying to discover fine distinctions in meaning, some research should be given, even if inconclusive.

Comment: It doesn’t matter what the difference is.  They are simply trying to express the broad category of things that could get entered here using a number of terms th feel will resonate with their audience whether they overlap in some people’s mind isn’t important.  If they just written, “accomplishment” someone, for whatever reason might have said, “my potential entry is more of a milestone than an accomplishment. Can I still enter it here?” They are trying to say “enter whatever you feel is important”

Comment: The milestone is inscribed "London 50 miles", the accomplishment is when Dick Whittington becomes Lord Mayor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A milestone represents a (very significant) step along the way; an accomplishment is a triumph in and of itself, even when it is also a milestone on the way to something else…

Comment: I've added the qualifier to bring out in a clearer way something I'm sure you agree with .

Comment: Robbie, do you have any resources (dictionary definitions, examples of usage, etc.) to back up this assertion?

Answer (score 2):

They are sometimes used as synonyms, however a milestone is a great accomplishment.

A milestone is more significant than an accomplishment. You accomplish something when you finish it. I accomplished combing my hair this morning. I wouldn't call it a milestone.

But don't just take my word for it:

> [According to Merriam-Webster online an accomplishment is "the act or
>   fact of accomplishing something."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accomplishment)

Alternatively,

> [According to Merriam-Webster online a milestone is "a significant
>   point in development", such as graduating from college.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/milestone)

Comment: But a milestone isn't just 'a step along the way'. It's a very significant step. Answers here may not be the finished article.

Comment: Uh… Devil, their relative significance is not the point.

An *accomplishment* is significant in and of itself. A *milestone* is not.

If it helps, substitute whatever you like for *triumph*

Answer (score 1):

The OED recognizes three definitions of milestone--the original marker on a road, a marker of progress, and the sense adopted in U.S. program planning (the only one where I quoted the first instance, to show that this is a more recent use).

> milestone, n. and adj.  A. n.
>
> 1. a. A stone or (usually short) pillar set up beside a road indicating >the distance in miles from that point to a particular
>      place.The reference in quot. lOE   may be to a Roman milestone on a
>      road in England.
>
>    b. fig. A significant stage or event in the progress or development of a society, a career, an individual's physical and
>      mental growth, etc.; a measure of progress or change. Cf. landmark n.
>      3.
>
>    c. fig. orig. U.S. A stage to be reached (in a project, etc.), esp. by a specified date; a target.
>
> 1958   PERT Summary Rep. Phase 1 (Bureau of Naval Weapons, U.S. Navy)
>   2/1   The progress information is based upon a sequence of important
>   milestones together with their scheduled dates for accomplishment.

So an Eagle Scout badge would be, to me, an accomplishment (I didn't look it up in the OED). Milestones can be accomplishments.  The words clearly overlap.  A project might be working on something, e.g., development of an application.